# How to install setup project to win10

Tags: windows, winforms, setup-project

I am using Win10 and developed an app which has setup project(with VS2013). It can be installed to win7 but cannot be installed to win10. Is there any settings on setup projects on the visual studio?

Update:

```
msiexec log is:

Action start 13:34:52: ExecuteAction.
MSI (c) (38:14) [13:34:52:291]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SECONDSEQUENCE 
property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (c) (38:14) [13:34:52:291]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (38:14) [13:34:52:291]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (c) (38:14) [13:34:52:291]: Switching to server: TARGETDIR="C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\PathFolder\ProjectSetup\" VSDNETURLMSG="This setup requires the .NET Framework version 4.5.  
Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again.  The .NET Framework can be obtained from the web.  Would you like to do this now?" VSDNETMSG="This setup requires the .NET Framework version 4.5.  
Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again." CURRENTDIRECTORY="C:\Users\xxx\Winform\ProjectSetup\Release" CLIENTUILEVEL="0" CLIENTPROCESSID="3384" USERNAME="Windows User" 
SOURCEDIR="C:\Users\xxx\Winform\ProjectSetup\Release\" ACTION="INSTALL" EXECUTEACTION="INSTALL" ROOTDRIVE="F:\" INSTALLLEVEL="1" SECONDSEQUENCE="1"  ADDLOCAL=DefaultFeature  
MSI (s) (18:84) [13:34:52:304]: Running installation inside multi-package transaction C:\Users\xxx\Winform\ProjectSetup\Release\ProjectSetup.msi
MSI (s) (18:84) [13:34:52:304]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (s) (18:6C) [13:34:52:307]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
MSI (s) (18:84) [13:34:52:313]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (18:84) [13:34:52:313]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (18:84) [13:34:52:313]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (18:84) [13:34:52:313]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (18:84) [13:34:52:316]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (18:84) [13:34:52:316]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (38:14) [13:34:52:317]: Back from server. Return value: 1603
MSI (c) (38:14) [13:34:52:317]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (38:14) [13:34:52:317]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting SECONDSEQUENCE property. Its current value is '1'.
Action ended 13:34:52: ExecuteAction. Return value 3.
MSI (c) (38:14) [13:34:52:317]: Doing action: FatalErrorForm
Action 13:34:52: FatalErrorForm. 
Action start 13:34:52: FatalErrorForm.
MSI (c) (38:14) [13:34:52:317]: Note: 1: 2235 2:  3: ExtendedType 4: SELECT `Action`,`Type`,`Source`,`Target`, NULL, `ExtendedType` FROM `CustomAction` WHERE `Action` = 'FatalErrorForm' 
DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control Line1 on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2826. The arguments are: FatalErrorForm, Line1, to the right
DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control Line2 on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2826. The arguments are: FatalErrorForm, Line2, to the right
DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control BannerBmp on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2826. The arguments are: FatalErrorForm, BannerBmp, to the right
Action 13:34:52: FatalErrorForm. Dialog created
Action ended 13:34:53: FatalErrorForm. Return value 1.
Action ended 13:34:53: INSTALL. Return value 3.
MSI (c) (38:14) [13:34:53:273]: Destroying RemoteAPI object.
MSI (c) (38:88) [13:34:53:273]: Custom Action Manager thread ending.

=== Logging stopped: 6.05.2019  13:34:53 ===
MSI (c) (38:14) [13:34:53:280]: Note: 1: 1708 
MSI (c) (38:14) [13:34:53:280]: Product: ProjectSetup -- Installation failed.

MSI (c) (38:14) [13:34:53:280]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: ProjectSetup. Product Version: 1.0.0. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: PathFolder. Installation success or error status: 1603.

MSI (c) (38:14) [13:34:53:281]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (38:14) [13:34:53:281]: Cleaning up uninstalled install packages, if any exist
MSI (c) (38:14) [13:34:53:282]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
=== Verbose logging stopped: 6.05.2019  13:34:53 ===
```

Comment: How did you created setup? What prerequisites do you check during the setup? What error/exception do you receive. What is written in the logs? Please provide more details.

Comment: Do you create your setup with visual studio installer?

Comment: @Mikev Yes I created setup project